# Properly moving javascript externally as functions and firing event

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the first time I'll try to move all the script from html file to an external Javascript file because I think it will be more organized to separate display from script codes.

So originally I have

**html**

```
<body>
<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle" >Menu</a>


<script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Which I tried to translate or move to an external file.

**html**

```
<body>
  <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle" onClick="showHideMenu()">Menu</a>

  <script src="myjsfolder/externalJavascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

**externalJavascript**

```
function showHideMenu(){

$("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        });
}
```

I know this may look like a silly question but I just can't get it correctly. But I know I need to move the script outside. Everything works correctly when inside the html file.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work because you didn't just move the code, you changed it. Don't add an `onclick=...` in your HTML, and don't wrap the jQuery `.click()` in another function. Just copy the content of the original `<script>` element into the `externalJavascrip.js` file as is (minus the `<script>` and `</script>` tags).

Comment: The way you did it first is proper, however, my guess is you include the JS file in the header section, so it's trying to assign the event to a DOM element that doesn't exist yet. Wrap it in `.ready()` to make sure that the event isn't registered until the DOM is loaded.

Comment: @p3ace - are you set jquery  js path in HTML page??

Comment: can tell me any error coming in console or not??

Comment: @DarshakGajjar Yes. I put the <script src ...jquery.js> before the closing </body>

Comment: @DarshakGajjar There are no errors, it's just not firing up. Actually it already did when I changed the order of the <script src...>'s

Comment: @p3ace - i have update my code can you please review

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. Not add the `onclick=...` to your HTML
2. Wrap your Javascript in the other file in `$(document).ready(function(){//your code here//});

## Edit

as nnnnn pointed out, since you are including the file inside the `<body>` tag instead of the `<head>` tag (where I normally put my scripts) then you don't really need the `$(document).ready()` wrapper.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Menu</a>
  <!-- <script src="your-file.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
</body>
```

## Edit 2

Using the `onclick` syntax would look something like this.

```js
//your-file.js
function menu_toggle_click(e) {

  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <a href="#menu-toggle" onclick="menu_toggle_click(event)" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Menu</a>
  <!-- <script src="your-file.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
</body>
```

Comment: The document ready wrapper isn't necessary, because the OP has included the script at the end of the body.

Comment: Can we add anything outside `body` & `head` sections?

Comment: @nnnnnn definitely doesn't need to, but also doesn't hurt.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Does this mean I don't specifically need to name the block as a function because I don't see any onClick attribute? Sorry, I really just got started with JQuery and has little knowledge with Javascript. Mostly focused on backend.

Comment: You are correct. the `$('#menu-toggle').click(...)` adds the event to the menu-toggle item. I'll update the answer with the other way if you want to use it.